Why did 黄 not have an adjectival form in Old Japanese?
A lot of online articles have claimed that Japanese "originally" only had four words for colors: 白, 黒, 赤, 青. They also argue that, since only these four have both noun forms and 形容詞 forms (白い, 黒い, 赤い, 青い), the other color names must've come later. For example, 黄 can only be a noun, and its 形容詞 is 黄色い, therefore it must've arisen later. The same goes for 茶 and 茶色い.
I find these claims rather problematic. 黄 is a very old word. In fact, its very form already suggests how old it is (possibly ko + i > ki, given the compound 黄金 kogane). It also occurred in the names for four basic metals, kogane, shirogane, kurogane, akagane. As far as I can tell, color-wise, it has always meant nothing mostly nothing but "yellow," unlike 緑 and 茶 whose names come from the things that have these colors, vegetation and tea. Some examples from Nihon Kokugo Daijiten seem to suggest that it used to also be a 形容動詞:

●黄なる泉(いずみ)
「黄泉(こうせん)」の訓読み。
●黄なる涙(なみだ)
(「黄」は古く「赤」に通じて用いることが多い)嘆き悲しんで流す涙。血の涙。多く動物についていう。
●黄なる物(もの)
黄金色の物。特に小判をいう。

These examples aren't listed in the other dictionaries I have access to.
So why doesn't 黄 have a 形容詞 for itself in Old Japanese? Or did it have one but that just died off for some reason? Is there any extant Old Japanese source that contains a potential 形容詞 for 黄?

Have you read the article carefully? It's 6 colors not 4...

Not an answer, just findings, so posting as a comment.  Looking at the NKD entry for 黄金, the oldest reading appears to be kugane. So if ku is the oldest reading for 黄, just adding the 形容詞 ending would produce kusi in Old Japanese. Such a word existed — but it meant "rare, mysterious, marvelous": 奇し.

Does the second link say 'it has always meant nothing but "yellow"'? The ニッポニカ secion there doesn't seem to discuss etymology at all. 日本国語大辞典 above in the same page seems to say otherwise: "上代では赤と通用されることが多い".

@aka 現在では、こんなにも多くの色名があるのですが、もともと日本語には「赤」、「青」、「白」、「黒」しか色の名前がなかったそうです。そして、この4色に「黄色」と「茶色」の2色を合わせた6色が、古くから日本語で使われていた伝統的な色名とされています。

@YusukeMatsubara I definitely missed that part. But the point remains that 黄 doesn't compare to 茶 or 緑.

@Vun-HughVaw 「古くから日本語で使われていた伝統的な色名」「じつは、この6色以外の色、例えば「緑」や「水色」などは、「い」を付けて「緑い」や「水色い」と表現することはできません。」「「色名＋い」が使えるのは「たった6色」」
It clearly states that 黄 is one of the old colors, and includes them in the only 6 that have 形容詞 variants. It doesn't even touch on that because it has 色 in it, then must've arisen later. And, your argument that it's very old is meaningless, the original 4 are very old, the other 2 are very old. does this necessitate that the other 2 must have been there from the start?

@aka Are we reading the same text? もともと日本語には「赤」、「青」、「白」、「黒」しか色の名前がなかったそうです. This paragraph insinuates that originally there were only four.
"your argument that it's very old is meaningless," It's old and it only meant "yellow" and possibly "red". It never meant anything than other a color. 茶 was a definitely a later Sino-Japanese borrowing that developed a new color sense, and 緑, originally meaning "vegetation," developed the color sense later. I thought I was being very clear about this.

@Vun-HughVaw what does "it's old and only meant yellow or red" have to do with anything? you're saying the paragraph's claims are problamatic becaause it says colors with 色 are new but 黄色 is old. No, it doesn't say that, it says ccolors that have both a 形容詞 form and a 形容動詞 form are old, the ones other than that are new. 赤 has 赤い, 黄 has 黄色い, 茶 has 茶色い, so old, 緑 doesn't have 緑い nor 緑色い, so new. THIS IS THE ARGUMENT. It's not giving you its reasoning for saying 黄 and 茶 are later than the original 4, you thought the text is saying something, then rebutted that. but it wasn't saying it at all.

形容詞 form and a 体言 form*, and I used 黄 and 茶 instead of ◯色 in some places for character limit

@aka For the last time, the way I framed my reasoning is this: if it's old and it used to mean something else, like 緑 and 茶, then there's a reason to believe the sense "yellow" was a later, LESS OLD, development. If it's old and always meant "yellow", there's a reason to believe it may not be comparable to 緑 and 茶, whose color sense were later, LESS OLD developments still recorded by modern dictionaries. That's what I meant by "old and only meant 'yellow'". If all you do is insisting on being obtuse, I cannot help you any further than this.

@aka 'you're saying the paragraph's claims are problamatic becaause it says colors with 色 are new but 黄色 is old.' I said what??? "Later" does not mean "new", and "new color sense" is "new" relative to its original sense. There's clearly a reading comprehension problem on your part here. Try Crl+F to see how many times I said "new" on this entire page. What do you think "new" means exactly? Like modern "new"? You can't even understand plain text and you're trying to paraphrase something that I never said?

@aka "you're saying the paragraph's claims are problamatic becaause it says colors with 色 are new but 黄色 is old." No, I'm pretty sure that article doesn't say anything about old and new. I cited it because it claims "there was originally only four words for colors". It doesn't explain anything about why we have to say 黄色い and 茶色い actually. I used the pronoun "they" because there are other articles and answers on Chiebukuro that claim the four "original" colors work differently than other colors.

@aka Take this answer on Chiebukuro, for example https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1263138717

@aka Read my reply to the answer below. I'm totally open to the possibility that 黄 might have meant something other than "yellow" (keywords: "might have meant", not "evidently meant"), and "yellow" was a "new color sense". "New sense" is different from the words themselves being "new". 緑 could be old, but its "green" sense wasn't as old as its original sense. 茶 was a Sino-Japanese loanword so it was never even as old. Try understanding what I say plainly, don't assume what you think I say.

While it may normally be fair to say that 黄 is a "very old" word, whether it's as old as 赤 and 青 is a different problem. Even if a word existed at some point, whether it was common or whether it referred to a color is a different problem.
Man'yoshu is one of Japan's oldest historical documents, and it's the oldest known waka collection. It already had many color-related words and kanji including 赤, 青, 白, 黒, 黄, 紫, 茜, 紅, 金, 緑 and so on. Usages and perceptions of colors by ancient people as expressed in these waka have been extensively studied, for example by 伊原昭. Based on them, people believe that 赤 widely covered the spectrum of brownish and yellowish colors at this point, while the use of 黄 (and 緑) was fairly limited. Although 黄 was used in the names of certain yellow things including gold (kugane), it was not well established as a color name. This research by 西王燦 is available online for free.


「黄」という色は、万葉集時代には、色名として十分には定着していなかったようだ。
赤という字が指し示す色は万葉集の場合、かなり広い範囲の色を表している。



It'd be cool to know if there's any theory as to what 黄 originally meant. With 緑, there was clearly a semantic development from "vegetation" to "green."

@Vun-HughVaw, regarding older senses, see also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BB%83#Chinese.  The etymology there suggests that this may have had an older sense of "bright" or "shine", and that this is cognate with 光 (reconstructed Old Chinese *kʷaːŋ or *kʷaːŋs).
